# ERROR 414 for Data URI's for SVG on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, base64, uri

After reading this [post](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) on CSS-tricks, I'm trying to pass SVG (base64 encoded with this [tool](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php)) directly inside my css rule, something like this:

```
.mysvg {
     background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]);
}
```

where data is the svg encoded.

The problem is that sometimes Chrome returns the ERROR 414 - URI too long.

What I don't understand why I have this error (it should not try to make any request to the server) and why it is prompted only sometimes (I mean I don't know how to reproduce it, it just happens and then it disappears).

Anyone had the same error? Does anyone know why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What's the size of your SVG? This thread indicated the limit in Chrome is 2MB https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44820#c1

Comment: The biggest one is 12K

Comment: It also display the 403 Error with the 414.